# login form for admin using html

Tags: html

How to create a login form  in html without using php. I'm doing this for an administrator account so that the admin information cannot be found on a database. 
Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: How will you validate the user??

Comment: Why no php? You'll have to use some serverside language to validate the user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you could use an htaccess and htpasswd file combination to handle authentication, but it's not very secure, if at all (HTTP BASIC authentication is insecure...). That would secure all of the files in the directory that the .htaccess file resides in (the .htpasswd file can (and should) be in a non-accessible directory by the web server).

Again, I VERY strongly advise you to NOT go this route.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to forgo the "HTML" requirement then you can still use HTTP's built-in auth capabilities [(relevant docs for `httpd`)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).

Answer (score 0):

You *must* use some server side authentication method analogous to PHP.  If there's nothing on the server, what are you going to "log in" to?  If your only authentication was some client-side JavaScript mess, a right-click and "View Source" would let anyone see what you're doing.